# Importing values and labels from SPSS with memisc

Tags: r, spss

I want to import both values and labels from a dataset but I don't understand how to do it with this package (the documentation is not clear). I know it is possible because [Rz](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rz/index.html) (a gui interface for R) uses memisc to do this. I prefer, though, not to depend on too many packages.

Here the only piece of code I have:

```
dataset <- spss.system.file("file.sav")
```

Answer (score 3):

See the example in `?importer()` which covers `spss.system.file()`.

`spss.system.file` creates an 'importer' object that can show you variable names.

To actually use the data, you need to either do:

```
## To get the whole file
dataset2 <- as.data.set(dataset)

## To get selected variables
dataset2 <- subset(dataset, select=c(variable names)) to get selected variables.
```

You end up with a data.set object which is quite complex, but does have what you want. For analysis, you usually need to do: `as.data.frame` on dataset2.

Comment: data.sets are S4 objects so have extractor functions. See ?memisc and follow manual. When you do as.data.frame() labelled variables turn into factors by default so the labels become factor levels as normal.  The ones to be careful of are numeric variables with a few labels (usually for different varieties of missing values). You need to set the "measurement" so these become numeric and system-missings become NA.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a solution to this that I like

```
df <- suppressWarnings(read.spss("C:/Users/yada/yada/yada/ - SPSS_File.sav", to.data.frame = TRUE, use.value.labels = TRUE))

var_labels <- attr(df, "variable.labels")
names <-  data.frame(column = 1:ncol(df), names(df), labels = var_labels, row.names=NULL) 
names(df) <- names$labels 
names(df) <- make.names(df))
```